# Make Image Blue Pytorch

Tags: python, image-processing, pytorch, color-space

I'm trying to "blueify" an image that I will use for a PyTorch application (AI), which works better with "bluer" images. Specifically, I want each pixel to be blueish. I will put the code inside a class which I will put in a transforms.Compose for and pass it to the torchvision.datasets. ImageFolder tranform key word argument.

I tried to use the PyTorch torchvision.transforms.functional functions (adjust_hue, adjust_saturation, adjust_brightness). However, I was always getting images with different colors (e.g. green & purple, red & blue). I will put them inside a class which I will put in a transforms.Compose for and pass it to the torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder tranform key word argument.

Can you please help?

Comment: welcome. please show your own attempt ([mre]) and why you aren't satisfied with the results (show the results too)

Comment: Nvm, I fixed it by blending it with a dark blue image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to blend it with a blue image.

```
from PIL import Image
import torch
import torchvision

class MakeBlue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dark_blue = Image.new("RGB", (224, 224), "#0000ff")

    def __call__(self, image):
        try:
            image = torchvision.transforms.ToPILImage()(image)

        except TypeError:
            try:
                image = torchvision.transforms.ToPILImage()(image.byte())

            except Exception:
                pass

        image = image.resize((224, 224))
        image = image.convert("RGB")
        image = Image.blend(image, self.dark_blue, 0.6)
        return image

# ...
transformation = torchvision.transforms.Compose((MakeBlue(), torchvision.transforms.ToTensor()))
# ...
```